# iOS MKAnnotationView LongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotationview

Hi to everyone and thanks in advance =)

I have a doubt related with MKMapView and MKAnnotationView. I need to show annotations with custom images on MKMapView. To do this, and following several tutorials and other stackoverflow answers i created my own class. EDAnnotation.h:

```
@interface EDAnnotation : MKAnnotationView
    //@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;
    - (id)initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier;
@end
```

EDAnnotation.m:

```
#import "EDAnnotation.h"

@implementation EDAnnotation
    - (id)initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{

        self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

        if (self != nil) {

            CGRect frame = self.frame;
            frame.size = CGSizeMake(15.0, 15.0);
            self.frame = frame;
            self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            self.centerOffset = CGPointMake(-5, -5);
        }
        return self;
    }

    -(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

        NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
        [style setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [[UIImage imageNamed:@"train4_transparent.png"] drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15)];
    }
@end
```

I've added several of this annotations to my map and everything works as expected. Whenever I tap on an image, a bubble showing some information is showed. The problem is that i need to be able to detect long press gesture over one of this annotations (in addition to the tap gesture to show the bubble). To achieve this, i've tried to add `UILongGestureRecognizer` to almost everything possible:

- The UIImageView commented in the class above.
- The 'EDAnnotationView' instance retrieved using `(EDAnnotation *) [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];` in viewForAnnotation callback. I've even tried to make this instance draggable and to listen for `didChangeDragState` calls in order to cancel them as soon as `MKAnnotationViewDragStateStarting` is triggered, but this didn't work as expected too.

Basically what i need is:

- if the user presses over the image specified in `drawRect` method of `EDAnnotation` the bubble shows.
- if the user long presses over the image specified in `drawRect` method of `EDAnnotation` receive a callback that lets me add a new MKPointAnnotation to the map.

Thanks in advance for your help =)

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be also that your gestureRecognizer conflicts with the gestureRecognizers in the mapView. This could happen, because the annotationViews are subviews of the mapView.To solve this problem use the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate. When you initialize your gestureRecognizer, set the delegate property to the class where you implement that protocol, more precisely these two methods:

```
#pragma mark GestureRecognizerDelegate
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
    return YES;
}
```

With easily returning YES in both methods the gestureRecognizer should react. Maybe some other gestureRecognizers from the mapView will now fire their actions too, but unfortunately it's not possible to do the delegation of the mapView's gestureRecognizers.

This workaround helped me, when I was adding a longPressureRecognizer to the mapView. i think it could help you with your issue too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried Delegate way of calling annotation?

Create a delegate in Annotation Class

```
@protocol AnnotationDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)shouldContinueAnimate;
@end
```

in implementation file

```
- (void)shouldContinueAnimate {
//add code for animating
}
```

Import the delegate where ever required `< AnnotationDelegate >`

In the image view class you can add both LongPressGestureRecognizer and TapGestureRecognizer for the image.

```
_longPressGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                          action:@selector(handleLongPressGestureRecognizer:)];
        _tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                    action:@selector(handleTapGestureRecognizer:)];

        [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:self.longPressGestureRecognizer];
        [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGestureRecognizer];
```

Handle the method:

```
- (void)handleTapGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {


        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldContinueAnimate)]) {
            [self.delegate shouldContinueAnimate];
        }
    }


- (void)handleLongPressGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldContinueAnimate)]) {
        [self.delegate shouldContinueAnimate];
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @user2998200. Thanks for your answer. I will try tomorrow and let you know.